# JavaFx TextArea Fixed Content Row Count

Tags: java, javafx

I have a fixed `TextArea` with 50 lines. If the content reaches 50th line, the 1st line should remove and the 51st line should add to maintain the fixed row count.

This behavior is same as application console which hide previous inputs after some point.

Currently I am clearing the `TextArea` after reaches 50th lines using counter.

```
public static void updateTextAreaTest(String text) {
    lineCount++;

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (lineCount <= 50) {
            txtAreaTest.appendText(text + "\n");
        } else {
            txtAreaTest.setText("");
            lineCount = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

I need to hide the first line while adding new line without affecting the performance of the application which has so many threads running.

Edit:
The `TextArea` is not editable. `TextArea` will update automatically without user interaction.

Comment: Is this only being updated programmatically, or is the user editing the text? If the user is editing, what do you want to happen if they enter text that's not at the end of the existing text? What if there's 50 lines and they enter a new line at the beginning?

Comment: @James_D no, the textarea is not editable. no interaction with user.

Comment: Do you want the old lines _gone_ or just scrolled out of view? If the former then you may want to consider using a `ListView` where each element is a line of text.

Comment: @Slow I want to remove the old line, if I keep old lines, it takes too much memory and performance issue, which is why I am thinking about this approach. I am expecting something similar as eclipse console or command line which has a fixed content row count.

Comment: Then `ListView` should make this easier to implement. When you add an element (i.e. line of text) check the size of the list and, if it's reached a threshold, remove elements from the start of the list. In fact, with a `ListView` you can probably keep thousands of lines in memory with no problem since it's a virtualized control.

Comment: contradicting tags: jtextarea and fx .. please cleanup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, a `ListView` might be a preferred option for this.

However, if you want to use a text area, you can achieve this with by setting a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) on the text area. The `filter` for the `TextFormatter` can check the number of lines in the proposed new text for the text area, and if that contains more than the allowed number of lines, modify the change to drop the first lines. Note that this solution allows for inserting text with multiple lines in a single action.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private int lineNumber  ;
    private final int MAX_LINES = 50 ;

    private TextArea createConsole() {
        TextArea appConsole = new TextArea();
        appConsole.setWrapText(false);
        appConsole.setEditable(false);

        Pattern newline = Pattern.compile("\n");
        appConsole.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change ->  {

            String newText = change.getControlNewText();

            // count lines in proposed new text:
            Matcher matcher = newline.matcher(newText);
            int lines = 1 ;
            while (matcher.find()) lines++;

            // if there aren't too many lines just return the changed unmodified:
            if (lines <= MAX_LINES) return change ;

            // drop first (lines - 50) lines and replace all text
            // (there's no other way AFAIK to drop text at the beginning 
            // and replace it at the end):
            int linesToDrop = lines - MAX_LINES ;
            int index = 0 ; 
            for (int i = 0 ; i < linesToDrop ; i++) {
                index = newText.indexOf('\n', index) ;
            }
            change.setRange(0, change.getControlText().length());
            change.setText(newText.substring(index+1));

            return change  ;
        }));

        return appConsole;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TextArea appConsole = createConsole();

        // Fill with 45 lines to start:
        appConsole.appendText("Line 1");
        for (lineNumber = 2 ; lineNumber <= 45 ; lineNumber++) {
            appConsole.appendText("\nLine "+lineNumber);
        }

        // add a new line every 2 seconds:
        Timeline demo = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), 
                e -> appConsole.appendText("\nLine "+(lineNumber++))
            )
        );
        demo.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        demo.play();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(appConsole)));

        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

One nice thing about this solution is that it is a "fire and forget" configuration of the text area. You create the text area, set the formatter on it, which automatically provides the functionality of never having more than 50 lines of text, with lines at the beginning being dropped if needed, and then the rest of your code can just call `TextArea` methods (such as `appendText()`) as needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking, Is this optimal solution for large scale application which has limit of 1000 or 10000 lines? Is there any performance issue drawback?

Comment: Counting the lines is O(n) in the number of lines, but using a regex should be pretty fast (you shouldn't notice). Finding the place to take the substring will be very fast unless your code tries to add a huge number of lines. It should be pretty easy to adapt this demo to any number of lines to stress-test it.